# How does a real time clock interface with a computer?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture

How does a real time clock device interface with a computer? I am currently desinging my own computer using memory mapped IO and DMA but I am curious how a real time clock would be used in such a situation without hogging access from the memory controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read for example the [HPET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Precision_Event_Timer) & [PIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_interval_timer) wikipages and the [Real-time clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_clock) one.

In practice, assuming your computer is fast enough, you could deliver periodic [interrupts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt) to your computer.

In the past, interrupting the processor at the frequency of the [AC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_current) current (e.g. 50Hz or 60Hz) has been very effective. That frequency is too low to hogging access from the memory controller (since today, most [RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory) have access times measured in hundreds of nanoseconds and even very cheap [microcontrollers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcontroller) have today [clock rates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_rate) of at least 10MHz. Your laptop's processor operates above the GHz; read also about the [MegaHertz Myth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megahertz_myth)).

Answer (score 2):

You could do what modern x86 does, and include a CPU instruction that puts the time in a CPU register (`rdtsc`).

On x86 it's actually a timestamp counter of "reference" cycles since last reboot, but it counts at a fixed reference frequency regardless of power-saving halts and changes to the actual CPU frequency.

So you'd probably want an off-chip battery-backed RTC to keep time when the computer is off, and either let the OS keep track of scale factors and offsets for `rdtsc` like x86 does, or allow the OS to program the CPU's internal time so the read-clock instruction gives absolute time in nanoseconds directly (e.g. split into 64-bit seconds / 64-bit nanoseconds values.)

Anyway, this gives *very* low overhead for getting the current time in user-space (a few tens of cycles, no switch to kernel mode, and no contention for resources like I/O shared by multiple cores).  So it doesn't matter that access to the actual battery-backed RTC is slow.

---

The reference frequency on x86 is the "rated" / sticker clock speed, i.e. 4.0 GHz for i7-6700k, regardless of its max turbo or whatever.  This is due to historical factors; `rdtsc` used to count core clock cycles and be directly useful for performance, then OSes started using it as a cheap time source.  But then CPU vendors introduced variable-frequency CPUs with power-saving that broke this, and only later invented this reference cycles thing and added the non-stop feature so the `rdtsc` clock doesn't stop when the CPU's clock real clock is halted.

You can sidestep all that by just designing it as a low-overhead wall-clock in the first place, with no expectation that it correlates with core clock speed unless that's convenient for you to design.  (e.g. have it count a clock input, and let the OS and/or user-space easily find out what frequency that runs at.)